# Check whether a field has the property `UNIQUE` in mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, unique-index

How can I check whether a field from a table is set as **UNIQUE**?

For example I have a table named `users` with a field `email` set as `UNIQUE` and a field `picture` not set as `UNIQUE`, I want before selecting check whether the field is set set as `UNIQUE` if not then don't do the `SELECT`.

I tried to `SELECT` then count the returned number of row, if more than 1 then it's not `UNIQUE`,

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE email='$email'"
//...some mysql php line later
if($count > 1){
    //return nothing
}
```

but it's not efficient, what if there is no duplicate.

What's the best way to check whether a field is set as `UNIQUE` in `PHP`?

Edit: no duplicate doesn't mean it has `UNIQUE` property

Comment: alternatively you can check via `phpmyadmin`

Comment: Your code should already know whether a field has a UNIQUE constraint on it; anything else is just reverse engineering your own application.

Comment: Basically I have a function to search by and the result should be unique (kinda like a slug), like `username=bob` `email=boby@dgf.fg` but if the username is not unique then the user could not do a search by username and I'd throw an error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [documentation of SHOW INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html) (found by @diEcho):

> SHOW INDEX returns the following fields:
>
> Non_unique -- 0 if the index cannot contain duplicates, 1 if it can.
>
> Column_name -- The column name.

Try:

```
SHOW INDEXES
FROM $tablename
WHERE Column_name='$field'
AND NOT Non_unique
```

Note that this assumes that there is no UNIQUE index that spans multiple columns. If there can be, then you might want to exclude these with a subquery.

Also note disabled indexes also show in this query (the possibility of disabled indexes is mentioned in the documentation on the `Comment` column). There doesn't seem to be a column reflecting this, so you might need to parse the `Comment` column if you have disabled indexes.

There's no need to compare `Non_unique` to a number - [MySQL uses 0 and 1 for booleans anyways](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_not)

Comment: @marc I'm pretty sure you did not mean to invert the logic? Without a word of explanation at least?

Comment: Argh, my bad, sorry. I got confused with the `NOT`. My appologies^2

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found it thanks to @diEcho

```
public function isUniqueField($tablename, $field, $connection){
        $query = $connection->query("SHOW INDEXES FROM $tablename WHERE Column_name='$field' AND Non_unique=0");
        $query->execute();
        if(!$query->fetchAll()){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Just because there's an index doesn't mean there's a unique index. You need to check that as well.

Comment: `SHOW INDEX returns the following fields:` `Non_unique -- 0 if the index cannot contain duplicates, 1 if it can.` `Key_name -- The name of the index. If the index is the primary key, the name is always PRIMARY.` `Column_name -- The column name.`

Answer (score 1):

You can check all indexed column with

[`SHOW INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html)

> if there is a **UNIQUE** index  then it cant be duplicate value  in same
>   table BUT a UNIQUE index allows multiple NULL values for columns that
>   can contain NULL

### update

to create a UNIQUE constraint on a column(let email) use below query

```
  ALTER TABLE  `table_name` ADD UNIQUE (`email`);
```

Comment: I need to return true or false in php

Comment: I want it return unique even if the field is not duplicated, just if the field has been set as UNIQUE

Comment: I didn't get you JonathandeM.

Comment: What i want is not a field not duplicated I want a field with the property `UNIQUE`

Comment: okay so you want to create a  UNIQUE constraint on a column? am i right

Comment: A don't want to create just check whether the field has the property `UNIQUE`, check my answer